# Finding condition if a quadratic equation have at least one real root given interval of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> Question: Find value of $a$ if equation $ax^2 + 2x -1 = 0$ has at least one real root for  $3 \leq x < 4$

I know if the restriction of $x$ is not given, I can use $D \geq 0$ to get condition for at least one real root, but if $x$ is restricted then how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the quadratic equation,

$$a=\frac{1-2x}{x^2}$$ and the range of this expression for $3\le x<4$ is

$$-\frac59\le a<-\frac7{16}.$$

Comment: Thanks @Yves but how to find range of the expression?

Comment: @golushailuoo7: plug $3$ and $4$, it is monotonic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the values of the quadratic at end points, viz. $9a+5$ and $16a+7$. There is exactly one root in the interval iff $(9a+5)(16a+7)\le 0 \implies a\in [-\frac59, -\frac7{16})$. [*Note we can’t have simultaneously both end points zero for any value of $a$.*]

The remaining possibility is two roots in the interval, which needs a turning point in the interval and the value at the turning point to have opposite sign to values at end points. The turning point is $x=-1/a\in (3,4) \implies a\in (-\frac13,-\frac14)$ and so the value at the turning point is $1/a-2/a-1=-1/a-1>0$. However it is seen $9a+5$ (or $16a+7$) is positive as well for allowable $a$, so there cannot be two roots in the interval.

Comment: Thanks Macavity, your method seems like good. But I am looking for something which can give me ans quickly in such type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Write the two roots and place them between $3$ and $4$ and then, first suppose $a$ is positive and multiple the three side of the inequalities by $a$ and solve them!. When $a$ is negative the process is like before.

Comment: thanks @GhD , but how I go further as we need to find condition for at least one roots, which means if two root between restricted interval it is fine and if one root between restricted interval it is fine too.

Comment: we have $a3$$\le$ $-1+ \sqrt{1+a}$$\le$ $4a$ when $a$ is positive. Solve $a3$$\le$ $-1+ \sqrt{1+a}$ and $-1+ \sqrt{1+a}$$\le$ $4a$ then take the intersection!. For other root do this and also you can consider $a$ negative and do like before.

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^2 + 2x -1 = 0 \iff x^2 +\dfrac 2a - \dfrac 1a=0$$

I see that there is a much simpler solution, But I liked the way this solution worked out.

Let the roots be $r$ and $s$. Then

$$r + s = -\dfrac 2a \quad \text{and} \quad rs = -\dfrac 1a$$

$$r+s = 2rs$$

$$r(1-2s) = -s$$

$$r = \dfrac{s}{2s-1}$$

If $\, s=3$, then $r= \dfrac 35$ and $a = -\dfrac{1}{rs}=-\dfrac 59$.

if $\,s=4$, then $r= \dfrac 47$ and  $a = -\dfrac{1}{rs}=-\dfrac{7}{16}$.

So $-\dfrac59\le a<-\dfrac7{16}$.